# General Topology - understanding of "equaliser"

Tags: general-topology, continuity, category-theory

I am studying a third year undergraduate topology course. We have the definition of an equaliser of two functions:

*An equaliser of continuous maps $f_1,f_2:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map $j:W\rightarrow X$ with $f_1\circ j = f_2 \circ j$ such that if $g:T \rightarrow X$ is a continuous map with $f_1\circ g = f_2 \circ g$, there exists a unique continuous map $h:T \rightarrow W$ such that $j \circ h = g$.*

Where, $X$, $Y$, $W$, $T$ are all topological spaces.

I understand what all the words mean in the definition, and so I suppose to could say that I do understand it up to a point. I'd like to get a better understanding of what it means intuitively.

For example, if we have the technical definition of the initial topology with respect to a continuous map, I understand that to mean that "We can't make the topology on the domain any weaker without breaking the continuity of the map".

What I think that I understand from the above definition is that "$j$ is a map whose image is the set of all of the elements of $X$ which are pointwise equal under $f_1$ and $f_2$, but certainly not more and not less.

Is this correct? Is there any more I can gather from this?

Comment: it's mostly just $((x) | f_1(x)=f_2(x))$, but in category theory deals with arrows, so it just looks different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you seem to get it.

Moreover, $j$ is an embedding of topological spaces, i.e. - up to isomorphism - $j$ is the inclusion map of $\{x\in X:f_1(x)=f_2(x)\}$ into $X$.

Now check that this inclusion map satisfies the universal property of the equalizer. 
Then that means we found it, as - by the uniqueness criterium - $j$ and $W$ must be unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: In topology, if a limit of a diagram exists, it's the same one as Set uses, and the topology is the initial or final one, depending on how the arrows go. This is a classical fact from categorical topology. I don't know who showed it first.